# Nested JSON from a input form

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I've been looking around for quite some time but I can't seem to find a way how to best create a nested JSON from client side input fields of sorts.

The end JSON i'd like to create should look like:

```
  {
  "DiaryEntry": [
    {
      "Date": "2019.xx.01",
      "Time": "14:00",
      "ThingsDone": [
        {
          "Activity": "Walking",
          "Duration": "1h"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Date": "2019.xx.02",
      "Time": "19:00",
      "ThingsDone": [
        {
          "Activity": "rolling",
          "Duration": "24h"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

(This JSON might be with mistakes, but I hope it's understandable).
Would be ideally if someone could give me some pointers on how to manage at least one nested level via an UI where the person could enter information in a form and that would end up as a JSON like that. I'm doing it this way so it seems to be the easiest way how to manage info and let users have as many dynamically generated input fields (E.g, he can make 100 "ThingsDone" inputs)

Open to other suggestions or pointers!

Comment: *I'm doing it this way...* - what way exactly is that? You need to provide your code and examples. All you should need to do is grab the values from input and create an object?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take some time to complete the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the help topic [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting. Good questions normally have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, StackOverflow has an [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) with lots of information. Thanks

Comment: @Ray this is a very generic question to ask in SO. We don't write code for you. We only check problems in already made code and tell you where the problem is. Please be (much more) specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in javascript, here is a way.

```
var activities = []

var activity = {}
activity.date = "03-21-2019"
activity.time = "14:30"
var task = {}
task.activity = "Walking"
task.duration = "2h"
var tasks = []
tasks.push(task)
activity.thingsDone = tasks

activities.push(activity)

activity = {}
activity.date = "03-21-2019"
activity.time = "14:30"
task = {}
task.activity = "Walking"
task.duration = "2h"
tasks = []
tasks.push(task)
activity.thingsDone = tasks

activities.push(activity)

var jsonObj = {}
jsonObj.diaryEntry = activities;

console.log(jsonObj)
```